# Unmarshal set of strings in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am using golang and want to store some data in Amazon DynamoDB in set of strings format `SS`. It is possible to store data but when I want to pull it back on unmarshaling stage it unmarshal every property except of prop that contain set of strings. Structure that I use to unmarshal in has `[]string` type of that property. I saw that `dynamodbattribute` have some specific methods for unmarshaling like `UnmarshalMap` and so one but I didn't find specific method for SS. Can someone give me an advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have created custom unmarshaler following that example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#UnixTime.UnmarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue

but I still think that I am doin smth wrong because it should be easier way to parse set of strings...